# Why is it not safe to minify textarea tags in HTML?

Tags: html, laravel, minify

I was using [this](https://github.com/HTMLMin/Laravel-HTMLMin) package to minify my Laravel blade view files, and found that it (intentionally) didn't minify files with the `textarea`, `code`, and `pre` tags. Now I understand why code and pre should not be minified, but why isn't it safe to minify textareas? [Relevant Github issue](https://github.com/HTMLMin/Laravel-HTMLMin/issues/95).

Comment: Any reason you didn't leave a question on the GitHub issue? Seems like the best place to get an answer for something this specific.

Comment: @TimLewis I thought the Github issues page was for discussing issues with the package itself, and seeing the widespread acceptance of the idea that textareas are not to be minified, I didn't think it was appropriate to ask why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For exactly the same reason as for `<pre>`. Whitespace is significant inside a textarea.

```html
<label for="address">Address</label>
<textarea id="address" rows=5 cols=50>1 Example Street,
Some Town,
Some Country</textarea>

<hr>

<label for="address2">Address</label><textarea id="address2"  rows=5 cols=50>1 Example Street,Some Town,Some Country</textarea>
```

(It **isn't** inside `<code>` by default, but can be for *any* element given the right CSS).

Comment: Snap, I was under the impression that you had to use the value attribute to specify the content. I understand now, thank you.